# undefined is not an object (evaluating'_this2.props.navigation.navigate') - React Native

Tags: react-native

I am having trouble navigating through screens with a simple button.
This is my App.js

```
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppStackNavigator/>
    );
  }
}
const AppStackNavigator = StackNavigator({
    Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },

      },{
        navigationOptions: {
          gesturesEnabled:false
        }
      })
```

Login.js

```
export default class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <StatusBar barStyle='light-content'/>
                <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='padding' style={styles.container}>
                    <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={styles.container} onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
                    <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
                        <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
                        <Image style={styles.logo}
                            source={require('../images/logo/logo.png')}>
                        </Image>
                        <Text style={styles.title}>
                            Sports Chat App
                        </Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.infoContainer}>
                            <TextInput style={styles.input}
                                placeholder="Enter name"
                                placeholderTextColor='#ffffff'
                                keyboardType='default'
                                returnKeyType='next'
                                autoCorrect={false}
                                onSubmitEditing={()=> this.refs.phoneNumber.focus()}
                                />
                            <TextInput style={styles.input}
                                placeholder="Enter phone number"
                                placeholderTextColor='#ffffff'
                                keyboardType='phone-pad'
                                ref={'phoneNumber'}
                                />
                                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                                <Button title='LogIn' onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}/>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                </KeyboardAvoidingView>
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }
};
```

LoginScreen.js

```
class LoginScreen extends Component {
    render(){
        return (

            <View>
            <Login>
            </Login>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I keep getting the error undefined is not an object (evaluating'_this2.props.navigation.navigate') whenever i try use the Login button in Login.js,
I want this to navigate to the home screen but cant figure out why this keeps happening.
If i try do it without the components it works fine.

[Click to View error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTjJx.png)

Comment: try adding a constructor in your login.js ```constructor(props){ super(props) }```

Answer (score 3):

Add a navigation props to `Login` in `LoginScreen.js`,  Because `LoginScreen` has props `navigation` but `Login` don't.

```
   render(){
        return (
            <View>
                <Login navigation ={this.props.navigation}>
                </Login>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import AppStackNavigator from "./AppStackNavigator";

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return <AppStackNavigator />;
  }
}
```

## AppStackNavigator

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

const LoginScreen = props => (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
    <Login navigation={props.navigation} />
  </View>
);

const HomeScreen = () => (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
    <Text>Home</Text>
  </View>
);

const Login = props => (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        props.navigation.navigate("Home");
      }}
    >
      <Text>GO to home from login</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
);

export default (AppStackNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen }
  },
  {
    headerMode: "none",
    navigationOptions: {
      gesturesEnabled: false
    }
  }
));
```

Comment: i added this to the LoginScreen and still no change, i also tired adding the constructor to the Login.js. same error keeps coming up

Comment: I have edited my answer, can you check if that helps ? @LiamRamsbottom

Comment: No I keep getting the same error. I think the problem is in the Login.js file, the emulator is pointing me towards the onPress function. I have edited the above question to add the emulator screen

Comment: Replace your LoginScreen.js render with below code mentioned by @Ian Zhong - Thanks

Comment: I tried getting rid of the button in Login.js and have the touchableOpacity as follows.

Comment: <TouchableOpacity
                                    style = {styles.buttonContainer}
                                    onPress={() => {
                                    props.navigation.navigate("Home");
                                    }}>
                                    <Text>Login</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>

Comment: Now it says cant find variable: props

Comment: You don't need to get rid of anything. Try adding the code below mentioned by @ian zhong. Replace your LoginScreen.js with that one. 
Basically you will need this, 

<View>
                <Login navigation ={this.props.navigation}>
                </Login>
            </View>

Comment: The problem was in index.js. I have a functions to invoke a splash screen there and thats where I needed to put the <Login navigation ={this.props.navigation}> .  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the navigation prop in the component. Check the official guide.

[reactnavigation Official guide](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/connecting-navigation-prop.html)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class MyBackButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
   return <Button title="Back" onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.goBack() }} />;
 }
}

// withNavigation returns a component that wraps MyBackButton and passes in the
// navigation prop
export default withNavigation(MyBackButton);
```